# Can't open PDF from asset from list button

Tags: android, pdf

I have 2 apps that I have PDFs in the asset folders.  In app A the code works perfectly fine but in app B it doesn't work.  I don't get any errors.  When clicking the button in app B it opens adobe acrobat but I get a toast saying "This file could not be accessed.  check the location or network and try again".  I even put the PDF in app A to make sure nothing was wrong with this PDF file.  It opened fine in app A.

Here is my code for app B.  I'm trying to open it via a button in a list.

[CODE]

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
static final String TAG = InteractiveArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

String ta = "helen.pdf";
GPXParser mParser = new GPXParser();

public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text,header, number, web;
    protected ImageButton web_pic, imageView;
    ImageView bike, atv, utv;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.bike = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bike);
        viewHolder.atv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.atv);
        viewHolder.utv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.utv);
        viewHolder.web_pic = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.web_pic);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {         

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MapActivity.class);

                    context.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }); 
        viewHolder.web_pic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    copyReadAssets();

                }       
            });
    }


    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.header.setText(values[position]);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map1);
    holder.web_pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pdf);
    holder.bike.setImageResource(R.drawable.bike);
    holder.atv.setImageResource(R.drawable.atv_2);
    holder.utv.setImageResource(R.drawable.utv);

    if (position == 0) {
        holder.text.setText("17.82 mi");



    }
    if (position == 1) {


        holder.text.setText("29.09 mi");

    }
    if (position == 2) {


        holder.text.setText("11.06 mi");

    }


    return view;
}
private void copyReadAssets() {

    AssetManager assetManager =context. getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), ta);
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(ta);
        out = context.openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(
        Uri.parse("file://" +context. getFilesDir() + "/"+ta),
        "application/pdf");

   context. startActivity(intent);
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

}
[CODE/]

Comment: even in App B, pdf is there in asset folder right?

Comment: Yes the PDF is in the asset folder of app B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to open PDF,

```
 in = assetManager.open(ta);

  String out= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ ta);

    File outFile = new File(out, ta);


  FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
  copyFile(in, oStream);
```

Comment: That's gonna try to open from my SD card right?  I want to open it from my asset folder of my app.  I tried it and got the toast "the file does not exist".  I moved the PDF to my SD card and it opened it from there.  But that's not what I want to do...

Comment: Uri.parse("file:///" +context. getFilesDir() + "/"+ta), "application/pdf");

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> add this in manifest

Comment: At "out = new FileOutputStream(outFile)" I'm getting "an instance of type 'java.io.FileOutputStream' can not be assigned to a variable type 'java.lang.string'

Comment: please try using another variable,
FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

Comment: It does the same thing as before.

Comment: you mean, are you getting same error? after changing below 2 linesFileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
  copyFile(in, oStream);

Comment: No.  Sorry.  Its back to what it was originally doing.  But using your code you gave me.

Comment: But I did nothing different than I had before.  Which I basically what your answer was.  I completely rewrote the app from the ground up but I didn't change anything.  I haven't used this site much.  Do I still mark your answer as the correct one?

Comment: If above lines of code are working. Pleae mark it as correct. It may help others. thanks